# Performance timing: average, minimum or something else?

Tags: performance, timing, latency

When timing my (web) application for performance/latency, should I use the minimum time measured in *n* runs, or the average? Or something else?
If it's the latter case, when to use what?

If your answer is going to be something along the lines of, "research it, dude", could you point me to a good resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the values, store them by time, with couple (time_of_the_call, response_time). Then you may treat these data with tools, draw graphs, make statistics.
I think an average, minimum, etc, is not sufficient, you need a set of measures.

For example you may put you data in a csv file and import in excel, or even use google graph api to draw real time graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Use **median** rather than mean (or average).

For reasoning, see the page [*Mean Delay Considered Harmful*](http://web.archive.org/web/20060902063833/http://www.internet2.edu/~shalunov/writing/mean-delay-considered-harmful.html) by Stanislav Shalunov (the author of [thrulay](http://web.archive.org/web/20060902063955/http://www.internet2.edu/~shalunov/thrulay/)).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to figure that one out your self. Are you benchmarking for

- Request throughput
- User experience
- Checking timeout thresholds

Depending on what you want your analysis to answer different metrics should be used.

Comment: You have to think yourself. For example if you have a timeout of 1minute, you have to do a benchmark for the percentage of request taking over one minute. If you want a widget to be sub 100ms for good User Experience you have to benchmark for the percentage of request taking over 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2012/02/13/non-geeky-guide-to-performance-measurement/
This is a good article on "response time" timing. (Websites.)